# js calls controller that returns view with parameters

Tags: asp.net, api

On my homepage`s side bar I have a href with onclick func :

```
<a class="c1" onclick="ClientOrders()" href="/"><span>My Orders</span></a>
```

The onlick func calls a method in my controller :

```
function ClientOrders() {
    $.get("/Orders/ListClientOrders/", { id: @UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result?.Id})
}
```

My method in the controller returns a view with parameter (list of orders) :

```
return View("Index",await orders.ToListAsync());
```

However, my homepage is just refreshed instead of being redirected to the Index of my orders. I run the code in debug and I saw that the code in the view is reached but it isnt displayed.

Answer (score 0):

solution :

```
<a class="c1" href="/Orders/ListClientOrders/@UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result?.Id"><span>My Orders</span></a>
```